# What penalty is there for dying in the original Diablo?

Tags: diablo

Title says it all. Is their any penalty for dying in the original Diablo (monetary, experience or otherwise)?

Answer (score 5):

When you die in Diablo 1, you are *dead*. You have to reload the game from your last save, otherwise you can "start new game" from the character menu with that character, keeping all your stats, but losing your quests, progression, etc.

Playing on multiplayer enables the dungeon shortcuts automatically (crypts, caves, hell) and you can use them at your leisure provided you meet the level requirements. In addition, death in multiplayer results in your items being dropped, which made pking for sport and profit a rather enjoyable activity.

Comment: Your items DON'T drop if you were killed by a player (including yourself with firewall) However if a pker hurts you badly and a monster finishes you off it works. You lose some gold when you die too ah and an ear in pvp.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the only penalty was that your items stay in the place where you died.

Comparing to Diablo II if you quit the game and start it again, you body will NOT appear in town.

**EDIT**

Found this thread where they discuss the same thing as you asked: http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?682535-Death-and-Dying

Comment: This answer covers the situation of death in Diablo *2*, this question is asking about Diablo *1*, where the mechanic is very different. Additionally, the link you have provided is not useful (for me it asks for log in information).

Comment: I think the user is talking about the first Diablo, but comparing it to Diablo II.